# Extract Features Using two Column Values in a dataframe from another dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a dataframe 1 which contains two columns nodes1_id , node2_id

And i have another dataframe which contains 14 columns including nodeid and 13 anonymous features

This is my df1

```
df1.head()

node1_id  node2_id  
6         5 
5         2 
4         6 
6         2 
2         3
```

This is my df2

```
df2.head()

node_id  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7  f8  f9  f10  f11  f12  f13
0        2  14  14  14  12  12  12   7   7   7    0    0    0   15
1        3  31   9   7  31  16  12  31  15  12   31   15   12    8
2        4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    7
3        5  31   4   1  31   7   1  31   9   1   31    9    0   15
4        6  31  27  20  31  24  14  31  20  10   31   20    5    7
```

I want to add these f1...f13 columns based on some similarity to my dataframe df1 i.e, in df1 comparing 1st row 6 and 5 using features of 6 an 5 how can i add in that row of the dataframe

Comment: Your question is unclear. Based on what I understood, you want to compute similarity score between features of  two ids in each row of df1 and add that value to a new column in df1. Please clarify.

Comment: yes, I want to compute similarity between two id's in df2 and add a column in df1

Comment: and this not machine learning related, please use the proper tags to get the appropriate answer.

Comment: This dataset is for link prediction using machine learning

Comment: yes the data set is linked, not the question. No Machine Learning knowledge is required here, thus there is no need of machine learning tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def similarity_score(v1, v2):
    # calculate your similarity score here
    return score

def similarity(id_1, id_2):
    # extract the rows from df2 corresponding to 
    # the given ids and convert them to lists, or 
    # numpy arrays. After this you can calculate the similarity score

    feature_vector1 = list(df2.loc[df2['node_id'] == id_1, :])
    feature_vector2 = list(df2.loc[df2['node_id'] == id_2, :])
    return similarity_score(feature_vector1, feature_vector2)

df1['similarity'] = df1.apply(lambda ids: similarity(*ids), axis=1)
```

Comment: Here feature_vector1 and 2 returns the column names only from df2